# Question regarding correct notation for indexing nested sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, notation

Let's say I'd like to apply a function to each element of each set in a set, and I'd like it to be flattened. My instinct tells me to do something like this:
$$\bigcup~\{\{func(A_{ij}, b)~\rvert~A_{ij} \in A_i \}~\rvert~A_i \in \mathbf{A}\}$$

However, would it also be correct to simply write:
$$\{func(A_{ij}, b)~\rvert~A_{ij} \in \mathbf{A}\}$$

Is the two level indexing implied when providing two indicies.
If not, is there another shorthand way to notate this kind of indexing?

Comment: $x\in y$ and $y\in z$ does not imply $x\in z$, so ranging over the elements of $z$ does not automatically include the elements of elements of $z$.

Comment: The subscripts ($i, j$) are pointless, even *wrong*: there's no index set or sets that these things would belong to. Did you just omit mentioning them?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of a set are not necessarily ordered, so index subscripts don't always make sense.

You could write

$$\bigcup_{S\in A}\{f(x):x\in S\}$$

or let the set-builder notation do all the work:

$$\{f(x):x\in S\in A\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as: $$\{\mathrm{func}(C,b)\mid B\in \mathbf{A}\text{ and }C\in B\}.$$
or if you're in a context where the [unary union notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions) is likely to be understood: $$\{\mathrm{func}(C,b)\mid C\in \bigcup \mathbf{A}\}.$$

Your expression $\{\mathrm{func}(A_{ij},b)\mid A_{ij}\in \mathbf{A}\}$ is incorrect, because you're applying the function to elements of $\mathbf{A}$, not elements of elements of $\mathbf{A}$. You write "Is the two level indexing implied when providing two indicies?" Certainly not. All that is implied by the notation $A_{ij}$ is that $A_{ij}$ is an object that is part of a family depending on two parameters $i$ and $j$.

In fact, the use of notation $A_i$ and $A_{ij}$ in the first expression you wrote is quite odd. Sets don't automatically come with indices: You can quantify over all $A\in \mathbf{A}$ without thinking of these sets as $A_0$, $A_1$, $A_2$, $\dots$. It would be more natural (and correct) to replace $A_i$ and $A_{ij}$ with single variables $B$ and $C$ like so: $$\bigcup \{\{\mathrm{func}(C,b)\mid C\in B\}\mid B\in A\}.$$